# Prismatic schema: removing unanticipated keys

Tags: validation, clojure, sanitization, plumatic-schema

My API is receiving some JSON data from the client.

I would like to use Schema to perform validation and coercion on the data I receive, but with one additional requirement: if there is any map key that is not described in the schema, ignore and remove it instead of failing the validation (this is because my client may send me some "garbage" properties along with the ones I care about. I want to be tolerant to that.).

So in a nutshell, I would like to perform a "deep `select-keys`" on my input data using my schema, before validation/coercion.

Example of what I need:

```
(require '[schema.core :as sc])
(def MySchema {:a sc/Int
               :b {:c sc/Str
                   (sc/optional-key :d) sc/Bool}
               :e [{:f sc/Inst}]})

(sanitize-and-validate
  MySchema
  {:a 2
   :b {:c "hello"
       :$$garbage-key 32}
   :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T12:29:51.822-00:00" :garbage-key 42}]
   :_garbage-key1 "woot"})
=> {:a 2
    :b {:c "hello"}
    :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T12:29:51.822-00:00"}]}
```

I haven't yet found a reliable way of doing this:

1. I can't seem to do it in a [custom transformation](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/wiki/Writing-Custom-Transformations), because it seems a walker does not give you access to the keys.
2. I haven't had any luck trying to walk the schema by hand, because it's hard to differentiate map schemas and scalar schemas in a generic way; also difficult to account for all the possible shapes a schema can have.

Is there an obvious way I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A third solution, credits to [abp](https://gist.github.com/abp/0c4106eba7b72802347b): use schema.coerce/coercer with a matcher that will remove unknown keys from maps.

```
(require '[schema.core :as s])
(require '[schema.coerce :as coerce])
(require '[schema.utils :as utils])

(defn filter-schema-keys
  [m schema-keys extra-keys-walker]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
               (if (or (contains? schema-keys k)
                       (and extra-keys-walker
                            (not (utils/error? (extra-keys-walker k)))))
                 m
                 (dissoc m k)))
             m
             m))

(defn map-filter-matcher
  [s]
  (when (or (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap s)
            (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap s))
    (let [extra-keys-schema (#'s/find-extra-keys-schema s)
          extra-keys-walker (when extra-keys-schema (s/walker extra-keys-schema))
          explicit-keys (some->> (dissoc s extra-keys-schema)
                                 keys
                                 (mapv s/explicit-schema-key)
                                 (into #{}))]
      (when (or extra-keys-walker (seq explicit-keys))
        (fn [x]
          (if (map? x)
            (filter-schema-keys x explicit-keys extra-keys-walker)
            x))))))
```

This [was described](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prismatic-plumbing/lLCEcSh4cpw) as the cleanest solution by the primary author of Schema, as is it does not require any change to the schema itself to work. So it's probably the way to go.

**Usage example:**

```
(def data {:a 2
           :b {:c "hello"
               :$$garbage-key 32}
           :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T12:29:51.822-00:00" :garbage-key 42}]
           :_garbage-key1 "woot"})
((coerce/coercer MySchema map-filter-matcher) data)
;=> {:a 2, :b {:c "hello"}, :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T12:29:51.822-00:00"}]}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I think, just found one issue: I tried it but didn't work right away on the data from the question: the map with the :garbage-key turns into nil, and it isn't valid against `:e [{:f sc/Inst}]`. Merging the maps with `:f` and `:garbage-key` it works. So if your data has the exact same shape as in the question, it won't work as is. Otherwise, I posted an edit to this answer with the merged maps showing how the matcher is used

Comment: You're right of course, I corrected the question. Thanks!

Comment: Note: With a more recent version of Schema, replace s/walker with s/checker.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Schema README](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema#map-schema-details):

> For the special case of keywords, you can omit the required-key, like
>   {:foo s/Str :bar s/Keyword}. You can also provide specific optional
>   keys, and combine specific keys with generic schemas for the remaining
>   key-value mappings:
>
> ```
> (def FancyMap
>   "If foo is present, it must map to a Keyword.  Any number of additional
>    String-String mappings are allowed as well."
>   {(s/optional-key :foo) s/Keyword
>     s/Str s/Str})
>
> (s/validate FancyMap {"a" "b"})
>
> (s/validate FancyMap {:foo :f "c" "d" "e" "f"})
> ```

So apart from your specific keys (which can be `s/optional-key` like in the example, or `s/required-key` like seems to be your need) you can have additional "relaxed" keys, something like:

```
(def MySchema {:a sc/Int
               :b {:c sc/Str
                   (sc/optional-key :d) sc/Bool
                   s/Any s/Any}
               :e [{:f sc/Inst}]})
```

---

**EDIT**: Found a "hacky" way to do this by adding a `:garbage` metadata and discarding those entries in the walker:

```
(def Myschema {:a s/Int
               :b {:c s/Str
                   (s/optional-key :d) s/Bool
                   (with-meta s/Any {:garbage true}) s/Any}
               :e [{:f s/Inst}]
               (with-meta s/Any {:garbage true}) s/Any})

(defn garbage? [s]
  (and (associative? s)
       (:garbage (meta (:kspec s)))))

(defn discard-garbage [schema]
  (s/start-walker
    (fn [s]
      (let [walk (s/walker s)]
        (fn [x]
          (let [result (walk x)]
            (if (garbage? s)
              (do (println "found garbage" x)
                  nil)
              result)))))
    schema))

((discard-garbage Myschema) data)
;=> :a 2, :b {:c "hello"}, :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T12:29:51.822-00:00"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thing is, I don't only need to ignore the additional keys, I need to remove them too (I know, that's weird).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part :/. I'm playing with a walker but found the same issue as you, it's not that easy to distinguish a map schema

Comment: Colin Yates helped me find a solution. Just need some time to Gist it.

Comment: Added a solution with a walker. It identifies the entries using a :garbage metadata. You could also do without the :garbage metadata by replacing `garbage?` with something like `(and (associative? s) (= [:kspec :val-schema] (keys s)) (s/Any (:kspec s)))`. The thing is I couldn't find a different way to identify a `schema.core.MapEntry` which is the type of `s` in those cases.

Comment: Hmm interesting, didn't know about that :kspec thing. I had something slightly different, using a coercion to a custom Garbage type. This seems quite solid to me, why do you call it hacky?

Comment: I called it hacky because it uses metadata in the schema instead of a "proper" schema, and also because it depends on the internal implementation of s/MapEntry. It works, but it might break in future version of Schema without notice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84089/discussion-between-valentin-waeselynck-and-nberger).

Answer (score 1):

There is a schema tool for this called "select-schema". See https://github.com/metosin/schema-tools#select-schema

From the page:

> Select Schema
>
> Filtering out illegal schema keys (using coercion):
>
> ```
> (st/select-schema {:street "Keskustori 8"
>                    :city "Tampere"
>                    :description "Metosin HQ" ; disallowed-key
>                    :country {:weather "-18" ; disallowed-key
>                              :name "Finland"}}
>                   Address)
> ; {:city "Tampere", :street "Keskustori 8", :country {:name "Finland"}}
> ```
>
> Filtering out illegal schema map keys using coercion with additional
>   Json-coercion - in a single sweep:
>
> ```
> (s/defschema Beer {:beer (s/enum :ipa :apa)})
>
> (def ipa {:beer "ipa" :taste "good"})
>
> (st/select-schema ipa Beer)
> ; clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Could not coerce value to schema: {:beer (not (#{:ipa :apa} "ipa"))}
> ;     data: {:type :schema.core/error,
> ;            :schema {:beer {:vs #{:ipa :apa}}},
> ;            :value {:beer "ipa", :taste "good"},
> ;            :error {:beer (not (#{:ipa :apa} "ipa"))}}
>
> (require '[schema.coerce :as sc])
>
> (st/select-schema ipa Beer sc/json-coercion-matcher)
> ; {:beer :ipa}
> ```

Comment: answers that consist mostly of external links are not good for SO, You should expand on this answer and provide relevant details to make it a stand-alone answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach (code below):

1. Define a custom `Garbage` schema types, to be matched against properties you want removed; if you want all unknown properties removed, you can use `schema.core/Any` as a key in your schema (credits to Colin Yates for telling me about this).
2. As a coercion step, 'flag' all the values to be removed by coercing them to an instance of the garbage type.
3. Traverse the data structure to strip off all the flags.

This has the advantage of making little assumptions on the internals of Schema (still in alpha at the time of writing), and at least 2 drawbacks:

1. Assumes the data is a combination of Clojure maps and sequences (not really a problem in the case of JSON input)
2. Adds another traversal of the data structure, which may not be optimal from a performance viewpoint.

---

```
(require '[schema.core :as s])
(require '[schema.coerce :as sco])
(require '[schema.utils :as scu])

(deftype ^:private GarbageType [])
(def ^:private garbage-const (GarbageType.))

(def Garbage "Garbage schema, use it to flag schema attributes to be removed by `cleaner`." GarbageType)

(defn garbage-flagging-matcher "schema.coerce matcher to detect and flag garbage values." [schema]
  (cond (= schema Garbage) (constantly garbage-const)
        :else identity))

(defn- garbage-flagger "Accepts a schema (supposedly that uses Garbage as a sub-schema), and returns a function that flags garbage values by coercing them to `garbage-const`"
  [schema] (sco/coercer schema garbage-flagging-matcher))

(defn clean-garbage "Accepts a clojure data structures, and removes the values equal to `garbage-const."
  [v]
  (cond
    (= garbage-const v) nil
    (map? v) (->> v seq
                  (reduce (fn [m [k nv]]
                            (if (= garbage-const nv)
                              (dissoc m k)
                              (assoc m k (clean-garbage nv)))
                            ) v))
    (vector? v) (->> v (remove #(= % garbage-const)) (map clean-garbage) vec)
    (sequential? v) (->> v (remove #(= % garbage-const)) (map clean-garbage) doall)
    :else v
    ))

(defn cleaner "Accepts a Schema, which presumably uses Garbage to match illegal values, and returns a function that accepts a data structure (potentially an instance of the schema) and will remove its values that are not anticipated in the schema, e.g illegal map keys."
  [schema]
  (let [flag (garbage-flagger schema)]
    (fn [data]
      (-> data flag clean-garbage)
      )))

;; Example

(def MySchema {:a s/Int
               :b {:c  s/Str
                   (s/optional-key :d) s/Bool
                   s/Any Garbage}
               :e [{:f s/Inst
                    s/Any Garbage}]
               s/Any Garbage})

((cleaner MySchema) {:a 1
                       :garbage-key "hello"
                       :b {:c "Hellow world"
                           :d false
                           42432424 23/2}
                       :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T15:49:33.073-00:00"
                            'a-garbage-key "remove me!!"
                            "another garbage key" :remove-me!!}
                           {:f #inst "2015-07-23T15:53:33.073-00:00"}]})
  => {:a 1
      :b {:c "Hellow world"
          :d false}
      :e [{:f #inst "2015-07-23T15:49:33.073-00:00"}
          {:f #inst "2015-07-23T15:53:33.073-00:00"}]}
```